# Get element with jquery using iframe window

Tags: jquery, iframe, window, liferay

Im using Liferay.Utils.Window to open a window (A), inside that window i open another window(B), when i close the window(B) i want to reload the parent window(A). I cant get to use Liferay.Portlet.refresh("p_p_id_IdPortlet") as it doesnt work...ok, no problem,i reloaded the iframe like this:

$('#' + windowId).find('iframe').attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });

Here is where my problem appears, when i try to run that code on the Chrome console i get 
"VM10008:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null(…)"

And the weird thing (really weird) is that if i inspect the elements of html, changing the tab inside chrome elements, i go back to console and i run the same code again and it works...weirdest thing ever. I think that when i inspect some element of the dom something is loaded, something that allows me to find the element im searching for. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

EDIT: I leave an example to understand: On Chrome console i write

```
$('.dialog-iframe-node')
<iframe class=​"dialog-iframe-node " frameborder=​"0" id=​"newAssignmentRoleDialogId_iframe_" name=​"newAssignmentRoleDialogId_iframe_" src=​"http:​/​/​localhost:​8080/​group/​catalogo-de-datos/​manage-people?p_p_auth…e&_assignmentroletoperson_WAR_abecebcatalogportlet_personFirstName=Eduardo" style=​"height:​ 485px;​ width:​ 1218px;​">​#document</iframe>​
$('#newAssignmentRoleDialogId_iframe')
null
```

As seen i search the element by class and it founds it, but it wont find it by id after it told me the element exists

Comment: Your JS code might be running wrt inner document so it won't elelment. Can you try using parent document? something like window.parent.

Comment: I have tried that, it wont work either, it access window.parent.but also there it cant find my modals id

Comment: The selector is wrong in `$('#newAssignmentRoleDialogId_iframe')`, as the id attribute of iframe is `newAssignmentRoleDialogId_iframe_`. Last `_` is missing in the jQuery selector.

Comment: Moreover, you can use `$('iframe_selector').load(function(){ // your logic goes here })` to wait for iframe to load and then perform your desired task.

Comment: Thanks, will check and tell you

Comment: Hello, your solution didnt work for me, finally i found a way. I used:
`document.location.href=parentURL;` where parentURL was passed by parameter, so that did reload the iframe. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution didnt work for me, finally i found a way. I used:
`document.location.href=parentURL;` 
where parentURL was passed by parameter, so that did reload the iframe. Thanks for your time